# Unforunately app is closed..Only design phase is done

Tags: android

I just did the design part of a project but it shows app is closed..I did not do anything to the Activity main so I cant understand the error. I am new at this so please help. thanks.

```
package com.example.calculator3;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;


        public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
  08-06 11:07:28.495: D/AndroidRuntime(1927): Shutting down VM
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927): Process:                com.example.calculator3, PID: 1927
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927): java.lang.RuntimeException:    Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.calculator3/com.example.calculator3.MainActivity}:    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class   Gradient
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):   at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):   at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):   at  android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
   08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
 08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
 08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class Gradient
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):   at com.example.calculator3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):   ... 10 more
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927): Caused by:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.Gradient" on  path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.calculator3- 1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
  08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
 08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
 08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
 08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
 08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:665)
 08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:65)
 08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
 08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
 08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):    ... 20 more
 08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.Gradient
 08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):        at  0   java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
 08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):        at   java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
 08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
 08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
 08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):        ... 26 more
 08-06 11:07:28.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Manifest..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.calculator3"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="AnotherActivity" android:name="com.example.calculator3" />
</application>
```

activity_main

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context="com.example.calculator3.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttondiv"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:width="275dp"
    tools:ignore="LabelFor" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

 <Gradient
  android:angle="265"
  android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
  android:startColor="#000000"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_gradient"
    android:text="@string/button9_fix"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
     android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonAC"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
    android:background="@drawable/btn2_gradient"
    android:text="@string/buttonAC_fix"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
     android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
   />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_gradient"
    android:text="@string/button5_fix"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_gradient"
    android:text="@string/button4_fix"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonplus"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonOK"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button13"
    android:background="@drawable/btn2_gradient"
    android:text="@string/buttonplus_fix"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button9"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_gradient"
    android:text="@string/button6_fix"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttondot"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_gradient"
    android:text="@string/button3_fix"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttondot"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_gradient"
    android:text="@string/button2_fix"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonmul"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonplus"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonequal"
    android:background="@drawable/btn2_gradient"
    android:text="@string/buttonmul_fix"
     android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttondot"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonAC"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button9"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_gradient"
    android:text="@string/buttondot_fix"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_gradient"
    android:text="@string/button8_fix"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_gradient"
    android:text="@string/button7_fix"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_gradient"
    android:text="@string/button0_fix"
     android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button10"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_gradient"
    android:text="@string/button1_fix"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonAC"
    android:background="@drawable/btn2_gradient"
    android:text="@string/buttonpercent_fix"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:width="65dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonequal"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonAC"
    android:background="@drawable/btn2_gradient"
    android:text="@string/buttonequal_fix"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button13"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonAC"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonAC"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonAC"
    android:background="@drawable/btn2_gradient"
    android:text="@string/buttonC_fix"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonOK"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button13"
    android:background="@drawable/btn2_gradient"
    android:text="@string/buttonOK_fix"
     android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonminus"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
    android:background="@drawable/btn2_gradient"
    android:text="@string/buttonminus_fix"
     android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttondiv"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
    android:background="@drawable/btn2_gradient"
    android:text="\u00F7"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Edit your question with Error logs and your XML codes. So that I can help.

Comment: either the issue is in R.layout.activity_mai or maniifiest file

Comment: logcat is added..please help.... :(

Comment: @AndroGeek I simply renamed the xml file to activity_mai...is there anything wrong in the manifest file???

Comment: try to clean the project

Comment: "AnotherActivity" this activity is there in your manifest file. is its definition there in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's no such tag like `<Gradient/>` and `android.view.Gradient`

If you are using a custom view called "Gradient" make sure you use the full path,

```
 <com.example.Gradient
 android:angle="265"
 android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
 android:startColor="#000000"/>
```

To make a Gradient background first create a xml file in drawable folder and use `<Gradient/>` tag there, e.g

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
         android:angle="265"
         android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:startColor="#000000"
        android:type="linear" />

    <corners 
        android:radius="0dp"/>

</shape>
```

Now use the drawable resource as your background in the main layout.

Answer (score 2):

Gradient is the reason your app is crashing. It's not allowed in a layout file.

For a more complete answer see the [answer below by Prokash Sarkar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31847893/4570004)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the Gradient widget. 
Try to remove  section from your layout file.

Comment: and add the Gradient in the styles.xml